# pull company name from reference table where a parameter is on the master table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables and 2 drop down menus.

- Table 1 is `user` table that has `companyid`, `class` and `category` columns
- Table 2 is `company` table and has `companyid`, `company name`, and `active` columns

The first drop down menu selects the category and my gridview can build off of that. The second drop down just lists the company names associated with what the first drop down is selected.

How would I go about building this query for the 2nd dropdown for the company names? I must not be seeing something.

Comment: Could you show how you populate those dropdownlists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first drop-down selects the category, and you want the second drop-down to only contain companies that match that category, then you just want an inner join and a filter on the selected category... something like this:

```
SELECT table2.companyName 
  FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.companyid = table2.companyid
 WHERE table1.category = @selctedCategory
```

Comment: Excellent @T Dang, please mark as the answer if it works for you!